# Websocket : Is it possible to know from the program what is the reason for onClose being called

Tags: websocket, jetty

I have a Sample  WebSocket Program whown below which works fine

When ever the user closes the browser or if there is any excetion  Or any disconnect , the onClose Method is
being called

My question is that , Is it possible to know  from the program what is the reason for onClose being called ??
Please share your views , Thanks for reading .

```java
public class Html5Servlet extends WebSocketServlet {

    private AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();

    private static final List<String> tickers = new ArrayList<String>();
    static{
        tickers.add("ajeesh");
        tickers.add("peeyu");
        tickers.add("kidillan");
        tickers.add("entammo");
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public WebSocket doWebSocketConnect(HttpServletRequest req, String resp) {
        //System.out.println("doWebSocketConnect");
        return new StockTickerSocket();
    }
    protected String getMyJsonTicker() throws Exception{
        return "";
    }
    public class StockTickerSocket implements WebSocket.OnTextMessage{
        private Connection connection;
        private Timer timer; 


        @Override
        public void onClose(int arg0, String arg1) {
            System.out.println("onClose called!"+arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(Connection connection) {
            //System.out.println("onOpen");
            this.connection=connection;
            this.timer=new Timer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String data) {
            //System.out.println("onMessage");
            if(data.indexOf("disconnect")>=0){
                connection.close();
                timer.cancel();
            }else{
                sendMessage();

            }           
        }




        public void disconnect() {

            System.out.println("disconnect called");
        }

        public  void onDisconnect()
        {
            System.out.println("onDisconnect called");
        }


        private void sendMessage() {

            if(connection==null||!connection.isOpen()){
                //System.out.println("Connection is closed!!");
                return;
            }
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try{
                            //System.out.println("Running task");
                            connection.sendMessage(getMyJsonTicker());
                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Date(),5000);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for `onClose` is the following ...

```java
    @Override
    public void onClose(int closeCode, String closeReason) {
        System.out.println("onClose called - statusCode = " + closeCode);
        System.out.println("                 reason     = " + closeReason);
    }
```

Where `int closeCode` is any of the [registered Close Status Codes](http://www.iana.org/assignments/websocket/websocket.xml#close-code-number-rules).

And `String closeReason` is an optional ([per protocol spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.4)) close reason message.